# slideDown() is perfectly smooth, animate() is NOT

Tags: jquery

The `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` functions work very smoothly on a div:

```
slideUp(el, done) { 
    $(el).slideUp(); 
},
slideDown(el, done) { 
    $(el).slideDown(); 
},
```

However if I try and change that to the `animate()` function so I can have a fade as well, it becomes jerky / choppy:

```
slide(el, done) { 
    $(el).animate({
        opacity: "toggle", 
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, "linear"); 
},
```

Any ideas why?

What I particularly don't understand is why only animate() is jerky - even when ALL i'm animating is the height. If I swap out animate for slideUp() and slideDown(), it works smoothly.

Comment: is `toggle` a valid value?

Comment: You should provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Comment: @Alex Yes it is: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties

Comment: Not really solving your problem, but my advice would be to do this animation in CSS only. JS animation is notoriously unreliable due to it not being hardware accelerated

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would love to, buy my understanding is that CSS requires absolute height values to animate height?

Comment: That's true. It may not fit your case if you need dynamic sizes

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
function toggleSlider() {
    if ($("#Slides").is(":visible")) {
        $("#Fades").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $("#Slides").slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#Slides").slideDown(600, function(){
            $("#Fades").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}
```

**Working Demo on Codepen**
http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/yVPbKq

**Another way it can also be achieved is using SlideFadeToggle.**

```js
$.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
}; 

$("button").click(function() {
   $("#something").slideFadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" style="display:none;padding: 10px; background: rgb(238, 238, 238); padding-bottom: 1%;">
      
    <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar tristique eros, nec hendrerit velit cursus at. Integer tincidunt ultricies mi, sit amet dictum velit euismod sit amet. Nunc facilisis enim sapien, eget mollis purus tempus sed. Duis eget tortor vel neque molestie hendrerit vel a ipsum. Nulla commodo eget felis nec dapibus. Nulla in aliquet augue. Nulla scelerisque condimentum lobortis. Suspendisse semper interdum turpis, laoreet condimentum quam luctus quis. Nulla in felis nec nulla dictum congue at nec est. Nam at dignissim mi, vel interdum nibh. Nam dapibus maximus neque, eu sagittis velit venenatis nec. Morbi eu mollis tortor, nec egestas justo. Duis et lacinia sapien, non ultricies velit. Etiam et lectus pretium, lobortis tellus sed, maximus massa.

Pellentesque pharetra ac arcu id vulputate. Suspendisse tempus sodales rutrum. Nunc dignissim metus sed augue pulvinar, a lacinia nulla lobortis. Nullam sodales id ex in varius. Maecenas sit amet est ultrices, euismod lorem eget, malesuada sapien. Curabitur sit amet pretium sem. Phasellus vestibulum imperdiet mauris, vel lobortis sapien luctus ac. Donec eget fringilla erat. Vestibulum mollis nibh sit amet sodales pharetra. Cras et dui non sem sodales semper. Donec justo nulla, iaculis at gravida id, congue eget sem. Sed maximus ac nisl ac pulvinar. Cras dictum mauris eget lorem blandit, placerat molestie nibh varius. Sed a libero pellentesque, pulvinar urna aliquet, malesuada leo.
  </p>
    </div>
<button>toggle</buttom>
```

Comment: No, I don't want one then the other. I want to both fade and slide simultaneously - just as the animate() code I posted does, only without the jumpiness.

Comment: @daninthemix I have 2 codes posted. One slides then fades, the second slideFades.

Comment: Does the second require jqueryUI?

Comment: @daninthemix No the second is solely Jquery.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work at all - please refer to my original code - these are animation methods called by VueJS on a transition, so I need it like this: `slideDown(el, done) { $(el).slideDown(); }`

Comment: @daninthemix can you add a jsfiddle, or else its kind of guess work.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/mvw1yyfg/2/ but it's not very useful at all, because it seems perfectly smooth. In the real world - in a real app, there's a million DOM elements beneath the element that is being slid, and surely it's THAT that causes the jerkiness, and that also can't be replicated in a JSfiddle without spending a week doing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129433/discussion-between-daninthemix-and-norcal-johnny).